# $.post with function based parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a jquery plugin that act as a loading link that sends a request to a server using `GET` or `POST` now the thing is really basic but I cannot figure it out, maybe I'm tired, hehehehe.

Here is my code

**Plugin instantiation:**

```
$('#load-products-button').loadingLink({
    params: function(){
                return {                        
                   provider_id: $('#provider_id').val()
                }
    },
    method: 'post',
    success: function(res){
         alert('ok');
    }
});
```

**And the code that makes the call is:**

```
var params = settings.params ? settings.params : null;

$[settings.method](url, params)
     .success(function() {
       settings.success.apply(this, arguments);
     })
     .fail(function() {
       settings.error.apply(this, arguments);
     })
     .complete(function() {
       //remove the loading html
       link.html(currentHtml);
     });
```

The thing is that when sending the post request the params are not sent because them contain a function call, the post request is delivered with no parameters.

If I replace the params with an object like `{provider_id: $('#provider_id').val()}` it works correctly but sending params on plugin instantiation is not working to me.

How to eval the params before sending?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, since `settings.params` is a function, call it as one. `var params = settings.params ? settings.params() : null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since params is a function, you will have to call it to get the values.
In you plugin, change your code to the following:

```
var params = null;
if (settings.params) {
    if (typeof settings.params == "function") {
        params = settings.params();
    }
    else {
        params = settings.params;
    }
}
```